# A continuous function mapping a space with a trivial topology to arbitrary topology.

Tags: general-topology, continuity

[image]

After looking at a few posts here on MSE, I am convinced this cannot be true in general.

If anyone can check this counter-example I have made, I would appreciate it very much:

$\underline{\text{Counter-example:}}$

[image]

Comment: Actually every set has two trivial topologies: the discrete topology and the indescrete topology. If $\tau_1$ is discrete, then the statement of the exercize is correct, otherwise is is not.

Comment: @Crostul In my topology lectures we refer to the indiscrete topology as the 'trivial' topology.

Comment: Likely they just mixed up domain and codomain. If $\tau_2$ is indiscrete, all maps $(X,\tau_1) \to (Y,\tau_2)$ are continuous

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[As mentioned by Daniel Fischer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1916420/a-continuous-function-mapping-a-space-with-a-trivial-topology-to-arbitrary-topol#comment3933939_1916420), this is likely a typo. As stated, the statement is false. For a counterexample, take $X = Y = \mathbb R$ and take $\tau_2$ to be the standard topology on $\mathbb R$ and define $f\colon (X, \tau_1) \to (Y, \tau_2)$ by $f(x) = x$. Then $f$ is not continuous, since $(1, 2) \in \tau_2$ but:
$$
f^{-1}((1, 2)) = (1, 2) \notin \{\varnothing, \mathbb R\} = \tau_1
$$

---

It's easy to prove the following revised statement:

> Show that a function $f\colon (X, \tau_1) \to (Y, \tau_2)$ is continuous, where $\tau_1$ is any topology and $\tau_2 = \{\varnothing, Y\}$.

**Proof:** Given any set open in $\tau_2$, we want to show that its preimage is open in $\tau_1$. Indeed, there are only two cases to consider, and each of their preimages are easy to compute and (by definition) must belong to $\tau_1$:
\begin{align*}
f^{-1}(\varnothing) &= \varnothing \in \tau_1 \\
f^{-1}(Y) &= X \in \tau_1
\end{align*}